# Code displaying second image first

Tags: javascript

I made this code which displays different traffic lights at different intervals. It works , however when I run the code it starts from the second image.

```
"red-yellow 2.jpg"
```

I obviously want the traffic light to start with my first image, but I have no idea what the problem is.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>  

<h1>JavaScript Code</h1>
<p>Traffic Light</p>

<img id="traffic" src="only red1.jpg">
<button type="button" onclick="ChangeLight()">Change Light</button>

<script>
var list = [{
  src: "only red1.jpg",
  interval: 10000
}, {
  src: "red-yellow 2.jpg",
  interval: 5000
}, {
  src: "green3.jpg",
  interval: 3000
}, {
  src: "yellowonly4.jpg",
  interval: 1000
}];

var nextlight = 0;
var timer;

function ChangeLight() {
  nextlight = nextlight + 1;
  if (nextlight == list.length)
    nextlight = 0;
  var firstlight = document.getElementById('traffic');

  var obj = list[nextlight];
  firstlight.src = obj.src;
  //firstlight.alt = obj.src;
  timer = setTimeout(ChangeLight, obj.interval);
}



ChangeLight();

</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: the first time the code is run, `var obj = list[nextlight];` ... and `nextlight` == 1 ... the second light (the first one may be visible momentarily though)

Comment: because in script tag your calling `ChangeLight()` at bottom ..

Comment: try `var nextlight = list.length - 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put down line `nextlight = nextlight + 1;`, final code would be like this

```
function ChangeLight() {
  if (nextlight == list.length)
    nextlight = 0;
  var firstlight = document.getElementById('traffic');
  var obj = list[nextlight];
  firstlight.src = obj.src;
  nextlight = nextlight + 1;
  //firstlight.alt = obj.src;
  timer = setTimeout(ChangeLight, obj.interval);
}
```

Comment: yeah but why ? Can you explain please.

Comment: you increment the variable before processing(setting `src`), it should be after this.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this,

```
function ChangeLight() {

if (nextlight == list.length)
nextlight = 0;
var firstlight = document.getElementById('traffic');

var obj = list[nextlight];
firstlight.src = obj.src;
//firstlight.alt = obj.src;
timer = setTimeout(ChangeLight, obj.interval);
nextlight++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may sound Stupid but did you try

```
<img id="traffic" src="red1.jpg">
```

this could be because "only" can be considered as a class. 
also avoid spaces in the images. use hypen instead

Comment: This actually is wrong. There is no relationship between the `<img>` `src` attribute and class name.

Comment: True! what I am trying to say is no spaces should be added in the src

Comment: What html spec supports this your claim?

Comment: Sorry, I checked it again, turns out you were right. Thank you